# Drag and drop area with react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, react-dnd, base64url

I'm trying to create a drag and drop area for uploading a single picture and I want to pass it to the application state in the base64 encoded URL using a function `onDrop`.

```js
import React from "react";
import {useDrop} from 'react-dnd'


export default function MyDropTarget(props) {
    const [drop] = useDrop({
        accept: "box",
        collect: (monitor) => {
                const res = monitor.getItem();
                if (res && res.files) {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = () => props.onDrop(reader.result);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(res.files[0]);
                }
        },

    });
    return (
        <div ref={drop}>
            Drag item here
        </div>);
};
```

That's how I use this component:

```js
<DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
  <MyDropTarget style={{height: "100px", width: "100px"}} onDrop={updateImage}/>
</DndProvider>
```

Since I am new to `react-dnd` I am having some problems. I got such an error `TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`
I think I do not understand the structure of `monitor.getItem()` correctly and will be grateful for any hint how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you need to make sure `res.files[0]` has a value (not `undefined` or `null`).

```
 if(res.files[0]){
  reader.readAsDataURL(res.files[0]);
 }
```

You may also try to check the type of `res.files[0]` is if that doesn't help.

Comment: strange if I add `if (res && res.files[0])`it doesn't go into the if block at all

Comment: It kinda suggests that `res.files[0]` is `undefined` or `null` (assuming that previously, with `res && res.files` condition it did enter the if block). Could you maybe provide an example on sandbox, so that we can test it?

Comment: You can as well try to output `res.files[0]` before an if statement and verify whether it actually has any value.

Comment: res.files[0] is undefined. I don't even know what to do in this case and where the uploaded file is stored.

Comment: According to the documentation, `monitor.getItem()` gets the item passed on `endDrag` in a drag component. Since it's a little bit different case I'd rather suggest using `Dropzone.js` (https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone). It seems to be doing exactly what you're looking for, and in usage example, you'll find file uploading. Hope that this will help :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try